# Read and get mail and attachment using tibico

Tags: smtp, tibco

I have a demand which must monitor an e-mail box using tibco and get the e-mail file attachment, turn your data and sends them to a ws.

It is possible to perform this activity using tibico?

If so, would link the components that I use.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. There's an Receive Mail activity in Tibco BW.

Refer [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.1.0/doc/html/GUID-E10FC6DD-AC6D-4187-B5AA-12ABCA516594.html).